Not able to launch FIrefox on a new user account
I created a new user in the root account using the
sudo useradd jdoe -c "John Doe" -s /bin/sh -d /home/jdoe
I was able to create the profile but when I go to open Firefox nothing happens. I am not able to access the internet on any of the new users I have created thus far. I have tried deleting and re-adding the user to no avail.
How can I get Firefox to open under the new user profile? Did I miss a set up in the user account set up?

You've not mentioned your OS/release details; as there can be added complexities & security changes in more recent releases (strengthened apparmor rules for 24.04, firefox running contained etc).  Trying to start firefox at terminal can be helpful, esp. if started with snap run firefox --enable-logging=stderr --v=1 or whatever is appropriate for your unstated OS/release.

This may be a snap issue. Try the apt version of Firefox instead https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466
